# Physical Meaning of Airy dispersive PDE

Tags: partial-differential-equations, reference-request

I see airy's equation $\partial_t v+\partial^3_x v =0$ in some analysis book, but I do not know where this equation comes from, so I tried to find an explanation of its physical meaning. This doesn't appear difficult at first, but search engines almost always give me the ODE $y''-xy=0$. I struggle to find what I want.

What's the physical meaning of Airy's dispersive PDE? I would be grateful if anyone could provide a reference.

Comment: [KdV](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Korteweg–de_Vries_equation) - looks related to shallow wave equations where the nonlinear term can be neglected.

Comment: I have seen Airy functions in a physical context mostly in the asymptotic analysis of integrals related to electromagnetism.  Most books on asymptotic analysis of integrals will have a section on Airy functions.

Answer (score 0):

It describes propagation of water waves on a shallow canal. You will find more information on this problem [here](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=&ved=2ahUKEwijspXz3ob4AhVLRBoKHfnfAwoQFnoECCYQAQ&url=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.math.univ-toulouse.fr%2F%7Eslecoz%2FS10-cours.pdf&usg=AOvVaw2ot6C9aP3hz9TEI5c5Naws).